# GeoLocation - Center a map

Tags: geolocation, leaflet, geocoding

I am creating a map with markers with the leaflet library.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
        center: [${mapCenter.lat}, ${mapCenter.lng}],
        zoom: 9
});
```

I am using this algorithm to calculate the center of the map based in all the markers I have to show

```
        double minLatitude = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double maxLatitude = Double.MIN_VALUE;

        double minLongitude = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double maxLongitude = Double.MIN_VALUE;

        for (ViewMarker marker : markers) {

            if (marker.getLng() > maxLongitude) {
                maxLongitude = marker.getLng();
            }

            if (marker.getLng() < minLongitude) {
                minLongitude = marker.getLng();
            }

            if (marker.getLat() > maxLatitude) {
                maxLatitude = marker.getLat();
            }

            if (marker.getLat() < minLatitude) {
                minLatitude = marker.getLat();
            }                       
        }

        double centerLatitude =     (minLatitude  + maxLatitude ) / 2;
        double centerLongitude =    (minLongitude + maxLongitude) / 2;
```

But as you see in the image, I wouldn't say that the map is in the center

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate a [`L.LatLngBounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#latlngbounds), insert the markers' `LatLng`s there, and then do a [`map.fitBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-fitbounds).

Alternatively, use a `FeatureGroup` to hold all the markers inside, as it provides a [`getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#featuregroup-getbounds).

Unless you know the basics of geodesy and map projections, do not use naïve solutions like `centerlat = (lat1 + lat2) / 2`, which is not true for the default Mercator projection.